# Unity - Connect to a server with UDP

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I am working on a project where the server logic is implemented by the client. I have no access to the server. From the client side, a couple of data is sent to the server on which the server applies computation and returns the result to the client. How do I establish UDP communication from my Unity client?

Comment: Before you ask a question, do a simple research. I am sure that you'll find if you just search for "C# UDP examples"

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are trying to call the Unity API from another thread.

Maybe this helps.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class UDPRT: ScriptableObject {
 static public string ReceivedMsg; // INPUT DATA
 static private UdpClient udpc;
 static IPEndPoint IP;
 static private object obj;
 static private AsyncCallback AC;
 static byte[] DATA;

 public static UDPRT CreateInstance(int Port) // RECEVE UDP
  {
   IP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
   udpc = new UdpClient(Port);
   AC = new AsyncCallback(ReceiveIt);
   StartUdpReceive();
   return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance < UDPRT > ();
  }

 public static UDPRT CreateInstance(int Port, string Host, string msg) // SEND UDP
  {
   udpc = new UdpClient(Host, Port);
   AC = new AsyncCallback(SendIt);
   byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
   udpc.BeginSend(data, data.Length, AC, obj);
   return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance < UDPRT > ();
  }

 static void ReceiveIt(IAsyncResult result) {
  DATA = (udpc.EndReceive(result, ref IP));
  Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DATA));
  ReceivedMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DATA);
  StartUdpReceive();
 }

 static void SendIt(IAsyncResult result) {
  udpc.EndSend(result);
 }


 static void StartUdpReceive() {
  udpc.BeginReceive(AC, obj);
 }
}
```